# repeating a specific cell in R

Tags: r, radix

I am quite new with R. I have a large data set where I want to repeat a specific cell for each individual. See below a subset:

```
dfX <- data.frame("picode" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6), 
  "Age" = c(0,7,14,21,28,30,0,7,14,21,28,30,0,8,0,8,15,21,29,0,0,5,7,14), 
  "IUGRsc1" = c(0.12,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.26,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.15,NA,0.19,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.3,0.23,NA,NA,NA))
```

I want to repeat the IUGRsc1 to each individual, i.e.:

```
dfX2 <- data.frame("picode" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6), 
  "Age" = c(0,7,14,21,28,30,0,7,14,21,28,30, 0,8,0,8,15,21,29,0,0,5,7,14),
  "IUGRsc1" = c(0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.26,0.26,0.26,0.26,0.26,0.26,0.15,0.15,0.19,0.19,0.19,0.19,0.19,0.3,0.23,0.23,0.23,0.23))
```

I tried with `for` loops but couldn't figure out how to let R understand what cell to repeat for each individual... Any suggestion?

Comment: See the `zoo` package and its `na.locf` function.

Comment: thanks, here is the clean data :

Comment: na.locf is a bit risky as it may repeat a value to a different pig code... If there any equivalent function that could repeat the value within the same pigcode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::fill()`

> [fill {tidyr}](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html)
>
> Fill in missing values.
>
> Fills missing values in using the previous entry. This is useful in the common output format where values are not repeated, they're recorded each time they change.

```
library(tidyverse)
identical(dfX2, fill(dfX, IUGRsc1))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of function `rep` with `times` and `each` options

eg.

```
IUGRsc1 = rep(x=c(0.12,0.26,0.15.....),times=3,each=6)
```

Comment: Thanks, actually the number of row is not the same for each pigcode, so R has to fill each IUGRSsc1 according to the pig code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two data-frames and use merge function. It is similar to v-lookup in excel and left-join in SQL.

```
df1 = data.frame( picode=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6),
                  Age=c(0,7,14,21,28,30,0,7,14,21,28,30, 0,8,0,8,15,21,29,0,0,5,7,14))

df2 =  data.frame(picode = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),IUGRsc1=c(0.12,0.26,0.15,0.19,0.3,0.23))

df = merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE, by.x = 'picode', by.y = 'picode', sort = FALSE)
head(df)
```

Thank You